# How to make search Bar in header?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

I try to add search bar into cell with identifier and the use this method `viewForHeaderInSection` which it's come up with an error of

> The search bar outlet from the UISearchController to the UISearchBar. Outlet cannot be connected to repeating content.

So basically I want to make search bar staying while scrolling the table view. This is my approach to make it work but it doesn't work.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You should create the UISearchController programmatically:

Create the UISearchController, put this code in `viewDidLoad()` or `viewWillAppear()`

```
var searchController: UISearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
```

Now assign it to `headerView` of `UITableView`. Write the below code in `viewDidLoad()` method

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: So in storyboard I don't have to add search view controller right?

Comment: yes, indeed, you don't need to add! You can to create and it will be displayed one time only! @asiandudeCom

Comment: It has an error. It said that CGRect is not convertible into UISearchController. @Sohil R. Memon

Comment: Thanks but still have some weird problem is it have some weird spaces between search bar and table view. Any insight?

Comment: @asiandudeCom can you just give me screenshot of that please?

Comment: with this approach when the user scrolls, the search bar disappears. Any way to keep it up ?

Comment: @KwnstantinosNatsios Then this approach is wrong. You need to insert `UISearchBar` separately in your `UIView` and below that add `UITableView`.

Comment: @KwnstantinosNatsios Check this for better idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23969587/is-it-possible-to-have-a-fixed-uitableview-header-while-using-sections

Answer (score 0):

If u want it to be always visible on top, u can also put the search bar in navigationBar(of navigation Controller) as its titleView.

`self.navigationItem.titleView=self.searchController.searchBar;`

And to make it fit the screen in all orientations, just add the following :

```
[self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
```

Hope that helps :)