# Issue with section header and table view cell in UITableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, header

I've done an experiment of creating a screen with the use of UITableviewController instead of using scroll view reason is the fields in screen may get dramatically change that's why I do that

Screen : [image]

All of those cells are static cells.

section header code

```
let backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "main_bg")
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: backgroundImage)
    self.tableView.backgroundView = imageView

    header.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    let lblheader : appLabel = appLabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 20, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: header.frame.height - 20))
    lblheader.text = "SIGN UP"
    lblheader.textFontsize = 14
    lblheader.textFontType = 2
    lblheader.textFontColor = 1
    lblheader.textAlignment = .center
    header.addSubview(lblheader)

    let btnback : appButton = appButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: lblheader.frame.origin.y, width: 50, height: lblheader.frame.height))
    btnback.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    btnback.setImage(UIImage(named: "back_arrow"), for: .normal)
    btnback.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.btnBackTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    header.addSubview(btnback)
```

Now when I scroll the table It looks as below:
[image]

I want to scroll static cell of the table under header section.
I know I can also use combination of UIViewController which contains Container and represents the Table view controller (Ref : [See this i used it already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28003602/swift-how-to-link-two-view-controllers-into-one-container-view-and-switch-betw))
If any solutions other than that.
Please guide me!

Thank you

Comment: You need a single header, y don't add a UIView and put tableView under that. Its easy ;)

Answer (score 0):

alternatively you can use UITableView's `tableHeaderView` instead of using `UITableView's viewForHeaderInSection` because Section Headers **WILL** always stick to the top of the tableview unless otherwise if you do some simple hacks

If you make your SectionHeader opaque and not transparent/translucent you'll understand. Try making a Custom Project (test project) where you create a TableView with a lot of Sections With Different Headers

Perfect example without creating the Sample Project would be the `Phone` Application (the green one) in your iPhone where the `Letters` are Section Headers and they stick at the top of your screen when scrolling

This is an example in *Swift 2.3*

```
let someHeader = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("", owner:self, options nil!)!.first as! SomeView

//this is not a real function just what you wanna do stuff
someHeader.customizeIfNeeded ... yadda yadda set frame assign values add targets etc


tableView.tableHeaderView = someHeader
tableView.reloadData()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `UIViewController` instead of `UITableViewController`and add a UIView as header in top of tableView

Refer this [maintain the header of a tableView fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23969701/360513)

Just an easy approach, hope this helps

If you have to use 'UITableViewController' look at below solution also

[UITableViewController (static cells/keyboard handling) and have a fixed header](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34173227/360513)