# UITableView Section Header Stop Position

Tags: ios, swift

Is it possible to give the section header in ui tableview an offset to stop programmatically?

So, that the section header stop 100 px from top?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23969587/is-it-possible-to-have-a-fixed-uitableview-header-while-using-sections

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)
{
    super.scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView)
    let inset: CGFloat = 73
    if scrollView.contentOffset.y < inset && scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0 {
        scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: scrollView.contentOffset.y, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    } else {
        if scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0 {
            scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        } else {
            scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: inset, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one

```
CGFloat newViewHeight = 40;

UIView *newView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.bounds.size.width, newViewHeight)];

self.tableView.tableHeaderView = newView;
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-newViewHeight, 0, 0, 0);
```

Section headers will now scroll just like any regular cell.

Answer (score 0):

You can use property of UIScrollView: [contentInset](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619406-contentinset).  And style for a table view [UITableViewStyleGrouped (.group in Swift)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewstyle/uitableviewstylegrouped?language=objc).
This is my example of such UI: 
[image]

If you want to avoid header moving, set [Bounce Vertical](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619383-alwaysbouncevertical) property to NO.

Comment: Thanks for the Comment, The UIEdgeInsets make the right thing with the header, but the content get also the offset, but I only want to stop the header earlier because the tableview is behind a transparent view