# Header View like twitter profile [Swift]

Tags: swift, uiscrollview

How can I made a header view like twitter profile that when I scroll down the background image stay pinned to the top.
[image]
In my code I've created a Xib headerView and I put it into a scrollView, now how can I made what I've explained before?
Links to articles/tutorial are also fines!
Thanks

Comment: Looks like a `UITableView` to me with a header and difference cell types.

Comment: It's not what I've asked ahah

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to have a fixed uitableview Header while using sections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23969587/is-it-possible-to-have-a-fixed-uitableview-header-while-using-sections)